# Array.prototype.find() unexpected behavior

Tags: javascript, arrays, find

According to this [MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), the find() method takes a callback function that can take three arguments: the current array element, the index of the current array element, and the array that the method is being called upon.

So:

```
var r = [2, 9, 11]; console.log(r.find(function(e, i, r) {
    if (e % 2 === 0)
        return e; }))
```

returns 2, as I would expect.

However:

```
var r = [2, 9, 11];
console.log(r.find(function(e, i, r) {
    if (e % 2 === 0)
        return i;
}))
```

return undefined (when I expect 0),

and

```
var r = [2, 9, 11];
console.log(r.find(function(e, i, r) {
    if (e % 2 === 0)
        return r;
}))
```

returns 2 (when I expect [2, 9, 11]).

Can someone please explain what I am not properly understanding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The find method executes the callback function once for each element
>   present in the array *until it finds one where callback returns a true
>   value.*
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

The callback return is only used to indicate if the current value should be the result or not. It's sort of like `find` asking your callback a  "yes or no" question for the current value.

In your second case, 2 passes `e % 2 === 0` and you returned `i`. However `i` is `0`, a falsy value so `find` skips over that and continues. Further values (9 and 11) don't pass `e % 2 === 0`. Functions that don't explicitly return a value return an `undefined`, a falsy value. In the end, no callback returned a truthy value and `find`returns `undefined`.

The third case, `2` passes `e % 2 === 0` and you returned `r`, an array, which is a truthy value. That made `find`, right off the bat, return the first item which is `2`.

Answer (score 5):

The callback you pass to `.find()` is assumed to return a boolean (true or false) value. The value returned from `.find()` is the value of the first element for which the callback returned a non-false value.

In your first example:

```
var r = [2, 9, 11]; console.log(r.find(function(e, i, r) {
    if (e % 2 === 0)
        return e; }))
```

the return value is `2` *not* because of `return e;` returning the value `2`, but because `2` is truthy. You can verify that by changing `return e` to `return true` or any other truthy value.

Similarly, in the second example:

```
var r = [2, 9, 11];
console.log(r.find(function(e, i, r) {
    if (e % 2 === 0)
        return i;
}))
```

your callback returns `0` on the first element (because `i` is `0`), but that's *not* truthy.